# Passing API data from one page to another in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Let's say I have something like this:

```
this.http.post('http://edomonitor.com/school-evaluation-api/retrieve_data.php',data, options)
.map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
     loader.dismiss()
    this.items=res.server_response;
    console.log(this.items);

    });
```

How can I pass the call data across all pages?

Comment: Which type of data do you need to pass across all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a dictionary object like this

```
savePedoData() {
    let data = {
      steps: this.count
    };
    this.navCtrl.push(PAGE_NAME, data);
}
```

and In second page

```
steps = this.navParams.get("steps");
console.log(steps);
```

you can find your data into the log

Comment: thanks for your reply. So, how will I now print out those data in let say profile.html page?

Comment: Your welcome, I had already told you in the answer, how would you print your object, just see edited answer